# How to access a javascript class method from an ajax call (or another thread)

Tags: javascript, ajax, multithreading, class, reference

Pretty new to javascript classes. Im having trouble accessing a method of my class from a thread (ajax post). Ive also tried MyClass.this.coolFunction but nothing works! i also cant assign

```
var THIS = this;
```

in the constructor as to access a class variable you must use "this.variable" but this from a thread does not reference the class

```
class MyClass(){
    constructor(){
        this.THIS = this;
    }

    coolFunction(){

    }

    fetchData(id){
        $.post("ajax.php", {id: id},
                function (response) {
                    THIS.coolFunction();//HELP! (cant access coolFunction :(
                    this.coolFunction();//does not work
                }, "    json");
    }

}
```

Comment: no that solution doesnt work. pls see my edit

Comment: @Barmar can you please unmark this as a duplicate. As javascript classes work different to nested methods

Comment: Not really. You access `this` the same way.

Comment: Remember, classes are just syntactic sugar for functions and prototypes.

Comment: Also: There's no constructor. Can you make a class without one? If so, how would that be different than just a function?

Comment: @Barmar i left the constructor out to leave focus on the problem. I have edited it. Your link does not solve the problem. To access a class variable you always use this. However in a thread or ajax call this will reference the thread. I would like to declare THIS for the class and not within every single method

Comment: The constructor is irrelevant. Either use a fat arrow function, or declare a new variable `let self = this;` in the original function and use `self` instead of `this` in the callback. Just like the answers in that question say.

Comment: `fetchData(id) { let self = this; $.post(... self.coolFunction(); ...);`

Comment: Yeah i can do that but id prefer to just declare a self once in the constructor but it seems impossible. But definitely preferable to declaring a self in every method